# How can I round up a number in cell to specific number in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have some product prices like

```
30,56
25,34
26,88
30,13
```

I want to to round them with a 0,50 limit

if the number is over x.50 to make it x.90 and if not make it x.50

is it possible with a function of VBA?

Comment: yes it's possible.

Comment: how can be done ?:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alternate solution:

```
=INT(A1)+0.5+0.4*(MOD(A1,1)>0.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this formula to round:

```
=IF(A:A-INT(A:A)>0.5,INT(A:A)+0.9,INT(A:A)+0.5)
```

[image]

**Explanation**

It subtracts the integer part of the floating number so and tests if this is `>0.5` so `A:A-INT(A:A)>0.5` means `(30.56 - 30) > 0.5` which is`0.56 > 0.5`

The formula means something like that:

```
If (30.56 - 30) > 0.5 Then (30 + 0.9) Else (30 + 0.5)
```

Comment: What should a value of **20,95** be rounded to ??

Comment: Although is rounding up or down it does the 32.35 to 30.50 and not 32.50

Comment: @Nikos *"it does the 32.35 to 30.50 and not 32.50"* that's not true, you did something wrong then. The formula works as intended. I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Use IF, MOD and RoundDown

```
=IF(MOD(A2,1)>0.5,ROUNDDOWN(A2,0)+0.9,ROUNDDOWN(A2,0)+0.5)
```

You may want additional conditions to handle fringe cases like a price of 0.